# Changing color of specific feature(s) with PyQGIS?

Tags: pyqgis, color

Imagine that the lines that i have drawn is simple pipeline network, represented by some simple lines in a vector layer.

How can i define a script that changes the color of only specific lines to "red"?

I tried to write a script from google sources but i failed dramatically. I managed to change the color of the all the lines but i need to specify the "red" color. So far my script is this, but its not working:

[image]

```
from PyQt4.QtGui import *
from PyQt4.QtCore import *
from qgis.core import *
from qgis.utils import iface

def change_color():
    active_layer = iface.activeLayer()
    """renderer = active_layer.rendererV2()"""

    renderer = QgsCategorizedSymbolRendererV2()
    active_layer.setRendererV2(renderer)
    symbol = QgsSymbolV2.defaultSymbol(active_layer.geometryType())
    symbol.setColor(QColor(Qt.red))
    active_layer.setCacheImage(None)
    iface.mapCanvas().refresh()
    iface.legendInterface().refreshLayerSymbology(active_layer)

change_color()
```

This is what i am looking for but with a script not manually
[image]

Comment: Welcome to GIS SE!  As a new user be sure to take the [Tour].  Please always include code as text rather than pictures so that it is available for searches and testing by visitors to our site.

Comment: When i tried to copy paste the copy from the Notepad++ it seemed ok and intended properly, but on the preview below it wasnt properly intended so i posted a picture. Anyway, this code is not working so..

Comment: You just need to format it by highlighting your code and clicking the **`{}`** button.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are almost there.  You need this:

```
cat = QgsRendererCategoryV2(1, symbol, "1")
renderer.addCategory(cat)
```

A full example

```
renderer = QgsCategorizedSymbolRendererV2("id")
active_layer.setRendererV2(renderer)
symbol = QgsSymbolV2.defaultSymbol(active_layer.geometryType())
symbol.setColor(QColor(Qt.red))
cat = QgsRendererCategoryV2(1, symbol, "1")
renderer.addCategory(cat)
```

Comment: maybe i didn't explain briefly what i am asking. Please see the new pic on my initial post

Comment: That is what the code will do, just change the 1 to what ever value the line is.

Comment: Well, it does make the line-1 red but it deleted the rest. The other categories are gone. Sorry for the spam but i need this for an uni project

Comment: It will, you will need a category for all the other numbers. Or use the rule based renderer